# How to create a loop with this structure?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am having a problem with a loop.

This is my code:

```php
$a = "dia1
    dia2
    dia3
    dia4";
$a = explode("\n", $a);

$str = array(
    "nama|tempattinggal|nama bapak|nama ibu",
    "nama2|tempattinggal2|nama bapak2|nama ibu2"
    );
$str = explode("\n", $str);

for($p=0;$p<count($a);$p++){
    ##the code for looping
}
```

The output should be like this:

```
dia1 nama

dia2 nama2

dia3 nama

dia4 nama
```

Comment: Values `nama` come from which parts of `$str`?

Comment: you can see from the format "nama|tempattinggal|nama bapak|nama ibu",
in the first section

Answer (score 0):

assuming  the result of the first explode is in $my_first_array (for clarity)  and so for $my_second_array
the you could use a foreach over the two array checking for isset values

```
 $a = "dia1
    dia2
    dia3
    dia4";
    $my_first_array = explode("\n", $a);

  $str = array(
    "nama|tempattinggal|nama bapak|nama ibu",
    "nama2|tempattinggal2|nama bapak2|nama ibu2"
    );


    foreach( $my_first_array as $key => $value ) {
       if (isset( ($str[$key] )) then {
          $my_second_array = explode("\n", $($str[$key]);
           echo  $value  . ' - ' . $my_second_array[0];
        } else  {
           echo  $value ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: for your code, i got result 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = "dia1
    dia2
    dia3
    dia4";
    $a = explode("\n", $a);

    $str = array(
    "nama|tempattinggal|nama bapak|nama ibu",
    "nama2|tempattinggal2|nama bapak2|nama ibu2",
    );

//    $str = explode("\n", $str);

for($p=0;$p<count($a);$p++){
    echo '<br>' . $a[$p] . ' ' .((isset($str[$p]))?explode("|",$str[$p]) [0] : explode("|",$str[0]) [0]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you make it not 1 line? Because I did not make it using echo

Comment: for your code, the result is like this
dia1 nama

dia2 nama2

dia3 nama

dia4 nama
error in "dia4". it must "nama2"